# Analyses of English word formation processes?

Tags: english, morphology, reference-request, words, derivation

I'm looking for analyses of the word stock of English which look at which word formation process accounts for what percentage of the word stock.

When I say "word formation," I would include here borrowing or conversion or even semantic change, basically anything.

Anyone know of any such studies?

I'll accept even things that use a very small sample size.

Also, any period of English is fine.

Comment: Try another forum, pal! Nobody here will answer or even dare to discuss such a question... It's against their retarded rules ;) I know it's freakingly stupid and goes against the basic logic of creating a Q&A site, but that's the way it is here.

Comment: Really? Why, what rule does it break?

Can you suggest any forum where I might get help on a question like this? I tried lingforum.com in the past but didn't get too much help on there.

Comment: I'm trying to think of what you're looking for. For instance, would a list of all the words in the OED with their OED etymologies suffice? Or is that too complex? How about the same word list, marked (Lat) (Fre) (*Gmc) (ON) or (Other)?

Comment: What I'm looking for is a study where someone took some stock of words of English, whether that be the whole wordstock of English or new words that entered English in the 20th, 19th, Xth century, or 1950-2000 and then analysed those words to determine what word formation process they were derived from. Of course you wouldn't take ALL of the words that entered the language in the 20th century, you'd use some sampling method.

Comment: @Newbie In what way would you think this question is against our "retarded rules"?